# Java XMLDecode and weak references

Tags: java, xml-serialization

My question is concerning the use of weak references in Java and how XMLDecode deals with this. Say I have two objects, A and B. B contains a weak reference to A. I use XMLEncode to write them to disk, and at a later date I use XMLDecode to read them back in.

As I understand it there is no set contract for when the garbage collector runs, so if XMLDecode begins by initializing B before A, there is a brief window before it initializes A when the weak reference can be broken unintentionally. Is this correct?

Furthermore, if XMLDecode happens to initialize A within the weak reference in B, and then attempts to use this instance of A when we attempt to load A explicitly from XMLDecode.readObject(), surely this could cause a null pointer exception if the garbage collector has run between the initialization and the assignment? There must be something in place to avoid this, or something I have misunderstood about the garbage collection process.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is an object weakly referred to by a weak reference present inside an instance of `B` , when you serialize and then deserialize the structure , the sequence of initialization will be :

1. Create instance of `B`
2. Create the weak-ref inside instance of `B`
3. Create the Object of `A`
4. Set the weak ref in step 2 to object initialized in step 3.

No where in these steps is there any scope for GC to collect the instance of `A`.

Comment: Is this because A is also referenced interally by the XMLDecode instance? or is this a timing issue, in which case could you provide a reference to the reasoning. Thank you

Comment: In retrospect, you cant serialize weakreferences to begin with, so this is a complete non-issue.